# Using nested Parallel.For

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

Consider this example:

```
var x = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++ )
{
    for (var a = i+1; a < 100; a++)
        x += 1;
}
```

When printing x we *always* get 4950. What about if I want to parallelise this?

This is what I come up with

```
Parallel.For(0, 100, i => Parallel.For(i + 1, 100, a => { x += 1; }));
```

**However** this does Not print 4950 each time I run it. Why?

Comment: @onof, how would you do that?

Comment: Parallel.For(0, 100, i => Parallel.For(i + 1, 100, a => { lock(x) { x += 1; }}));

Comment: But locking 'x', would defeat the purpose of at least the inner "parallel" loop.

Comment: @onof x is a value type in this example. lock can only be used with reference types.

Comment: @chibacity right. He has to wrap it

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Parallel Extensions helps you with task creation, allocation, running and rendezvous, in a near-imperative syntax. What it **doesn't** do is take care of every kind of thread safety (one of the [pitfalls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997403.aspx?ppud=4)). You are trying to make parallel threads simultaneously update a single shared variable. To do anything like this correctly, you have to introduce e.g. locking.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do. I assume your code is just a placeholder or experiment. Parallelization is only suitable when you can isolate your different pieces of work; not when you constantly have to rendezvous with shared data.

Comment: The data I have is only read, there's just one variable (collection) that I add results to, and I do not care about the order they were added here. Is locking a slow mechanizm?

Comment: Extreme locking can give you **worse** performance than the simple sequential implementation. Consider using e.g. `Parallel.Aggregate()` to combine your results instead. Look at e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163340.aspx.

Answer (score 3):

Here would be the "correct" way of doing it, this would not require you to lock on your final total object and would only require you to do the interlocked operations at the end of each local thread's looping.

```
int x = 0;
Parallel.For(0, 100,
    () => 0, //LocalInit
    (i, loopstate, outerlocal) =>
    {
        Parallel.For(i + 1, 100,
            () => 0, //LocalInit
            (a, loopState, innerLocal) => { return innerLocal + 1; },
            (innerLocal) => Interlocked.Add(ref outerlocal, innerLocal)); //Local Final
        return outerlocal;
    },
    (outerLocal) => Interlocked.Add(ref x, outerLocal)); //Local Final
```

However, having two nested `Parallel` statements doing this little of work is likely a bad idea. There is a overhead cost that needs to be considered, if you are doing such small amount of work it would be much better to do only one `Parallel` statement or have none at all.

I highly recommend you go download and read [Patterns for Parallel Programming](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19222), it goes in to good detail about why small nested parallel loops like this are not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to locking each time, you could use thread-local variables in combination with a lock:

```
Object thisLock = new Object();
var globalSum = 0;
System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For(0, 100, i => {
    System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For(i + 1, 100, () => 0, (num, loopState, subSum) => ++subSum, subSum => { 
        lock(thisLock) { globalSum += subSum; }
    });
});

Console.WriteLine(globalSum);
```

Comment: @MattSmith Yeah sorry, it got kinda messed up when copying it from Visual Studio :) Will fix it