# Python joblib - Running parallel code within parallel code

Tags: python, performance, parallel-processing, joblib, parallelism-amdahl

I am working on a project that I intend to make more efficient by using a parallel function with **`joblib`** with shared memory.

However, I also intend to conduct a parametric study on the program by running the process a large number of times with different parameters (i.e. without shared memory).

I was wondering if this was doable in Python/`joblib`.

---

### Edit : *<sub>2020-06-19</sub>*

As another user mentioned, I should, I will clarify what in my code I wanted to parallelized. Essentially I have a 3D numpy array representing some physical space, which I populate with a large number of truncated Gaussians (only affecting a finite number of elements). Full vectorization was not found to particularly speed up the code due to the bottleneck being memory access, and I wanted to try parallelization, since I iterate over all *`ith`*-Gaussian centers and add its contributions to the overall field. (These loops will share variables to an extent)

The idea of parallel code within parallel code coming up is that I will also want to run a large number of such processes simultaneously using cluster accessed online in order to conduct a parametric study of the overall performance of the project as a whole in regards to an unspecified metric. Thus these loops would be fully independent.

A modified excerpt of the inner loop is posted [*here*](https://pastebin.com/ZdBQ61Y3). Unfortunately it does not seem to speed up performance, and in the case where I do not split up the list of Gaussian centers into two arrays for each core it is even worse, and I am currently investigating this.

---

```
import numpy as np
import time
from joblib import Parallel, delayed, parallel_backend
from extra_fns import *

time.perf_counter()
nj = 2
set_par = True
split_var = True

# define 3d grid
nd = 3
nx = 250
ny = 250
nz = 250
x = np.linspace(0, 1, nx)
y = np.linspace(0, 1, ny)
z = np.linspace(0, 1, nz)

# positions of gaussians in space
pgrid = np.linspace(0.05, 0.95 , 20)
Xp, Yp, Zp = np.meshgrid(pgrid,pgrid,pgrid)
xp = Xp.ravel()
yp = Yp.ravel()
zp = Zp.ravel()
Np = np.size(xp)
s = np.ones(Np) # intensity of each gaussian
# compact gaussian representation
sigma = x[1]-x[0]
max_dist = sigma*(-2*np.log(10e-3))

# 3D domain: 
I = np.zeros((ny, nx, nz))
dx = x[1] - x[0]
dy = y[1] - y[0]
dz = z[1] - z[0]


dix = np.ceil(max_dist/dx)
diy = np.ceil(max_dist/dy)
diz = np.ceil(max_dist/dz)

def run_test(set_par, split_var, xp, yp, zp, s):
    def add_loc_gaussian(i):
        ix = round((xp[i] - x[0]) / dx)
        iy = round((yp[i] - y[0]) / dy)
        iz = round((zp[i] - z[0]) / dz)
        iix = np.arange(max(0, ix - dix), min(nx, ix + dix), 1, dtype=int)
        iiy = np.arange(max(0, iy - diy), min(ny, iy + diy), 1, dtype=int)
        iiz = np.arange(max(0, iz - diz), min(nz, iz + diz), 1, dtype=int)
        ddx = dx * iix - xp[i]
        ddy = dy * iiy - yp[i]
        ddz = dz * iiz - zp[i]
        gx = np.exp(-1 / (2 * sigma ** 2) * ddx ** 2)
        gy = np.exp(-1 / (2 * sigma ** 2) * ddy ** 2)
        gz = np.exp(-1 / (2 * sigma ** 2) * ddz ** 2)
        gx = gx[np.newaxis,:, np.newaxis]
        gy = gy[:,np.newaxis, np.newaxis]
        gz = gz[np.newaxis, np.newaxis, :]
        I[np.ix_(iiy, iix, iiz)] += s[i] * gy*gx*gz

    if set_par and split_var: # case 1
        mp = int(Np/nj) # hard code this test fn for two cores
        xp_list = [xp[:mp],xp[mp:]]
        yp_list = [yp[:mp],yp[mp:]]
        zp_list = [zp[:mp],zp[mp:]]
        sp_list = [s[:mp],s[mp:]]

        def core_loop(j):
            xpt = xp_list[j]
            ypt = yp_list[j]
            zpt = zp_list[j]
            spt = sp_list[j]

            def add_loc_gaussian_s(i):
                ix = round((xpt[i] - x[0]) / dx)
                iy = round((ypt[i] - y[0]) / dy)
                iz = round((zpt[i] - z[0]) / dz)
                iix = np.arange(max(0, ix - dix), min(nx, ix + dix), 1, dtype=int)
                iiy = np.arange(max(0, iy - diy), min(ny, iy + diy), 1, dtype=int)
                iiz = np.arange(max(0, iz - diz), min(nz, iz + diz), 1, dtype=int)
                ddx = dx * iix - xpt[i]
                ddy = dy * iiy - ypt[i]
                ddz = dz * iiz - zpt[i]
                gx = np.exp(-1 / (2 * sigma ** 2) * ddx ** 2)
                gy = np.exp(-1 / (2 * sigma ** 2) * ddy ** 2)
                gz = np.exp(-1 / (2 * sigma ** 2) * ddz ** 2)
                gx = gx[np.newaxis, :, np.newaxis]
                gy = gy[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis]
                gz = gz[np.newaxis, np.newaxis, :]
                I[np.ix_(iiy, iix, iiz)] += spt[i] * gy * gx * gz

            for i in range(np.size(xpt)):
                add_loc_gaussian_s(i)

        Parallel(n_jobs=2, require='sharedmem')(delayed(core_loop)(i) for i in range(2))

    elif set_par: # case 2
        Parallel(n_jobs=nj, require='sharedmem')(delayed(add_loc_gaussian)(i) for i in range(Np))

    else: # case 3
        for i in range(0,Np):
            add_loc_gaussian(i)

run_test(set_par, split_var, xp, yp, zp, s)
print("Time taken: {} s".format(time.perf_counter()))
```

Comment: It's just a simple conceptual question. There are other similar questions such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26707177/parallel-within-parallel-code, and I am simply asking the same question in regards to specifically Python's capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

> *"... **doable** in Python/`joblib` ..."*

There is no problem with conceptual intent, yet ...

> *"... I intend to **make more efficient** ..."*

this is ***the hardest part*** of the story.

---

### Why ?

CPU microoperation **`NOP`** ( do nothing ) takes `~ 0.1 [ns]` in 2020/2H.

CPU microoperations take about `~ 0.3 [ns]` **`ADD/SUB,`** `~ 10 [ns]` **`DIV`** in 2020/2H.

CPU can have more than one core and CISC architectures can operate a pair of hardware threads on each of such CPU core.

[image]

CPU can evolve, will evolve, yet will not do any magic leapfrog *"jumps"* beyond the reality of constraints put into the game by the laws of physics. Never.

CPU can be scheduled by the O/S scheduler to interleave many more software threads ( streams of code-execution ) as this interleaved code-executions generates for us, slow, with about 25-Hz cortex visual sampling comprehension, using not more than only one (voice) or two-handed input "devices", an illusion of multi-tasking operating system, yet all such work is just sufficiently enough (no warranties for non Real-Time (HRT) operating systems) put into a few pairs of CPU-core threads.

CPU can achieve the most efficient processing, if the computing tasks are not wildly interleaved. The less the better.

CPU will in such "compact" work-stream orchestration remain within those about `~ 0.3 ~ 10 [ns]` per uop (a CPU hardware machine instruction) and will best compute, if not going anywhere else for data but into its own hardware registers ( L1 cache "costs" `~ 0.5 [ns]` to fetch data from, whereas L2 is **`~ 8x`** more "expensive", L3 is **`~ 40x`** more expensive and RAM can go anywhere from **`~70 .. 3++ [ns]`** to fetch data from ). Interleaved process-executions are thus paying a lot of overhead costs just to re-instate data many times pre-fetched from expensive RAM into less expensive L3, L2 and L1 cache storage ( just re-paying the costs of `~ 300 ~ 350 [ns]` each time a piece of data is to get re-fetched since interleaved process-execution does not retain once pre-fetched data after scheduler removed this thread from CPU-core so as to make a space-time for executing another one in the scheduler queue ).

CPU can do its best if not waiting for data from RAM ( memory channels and I/O-bottlenecks are known HPC-efficiency / [CPU-starvation enemies for ages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33065382) ).

---

### These hardware overheads are not *"enough"*, you will have to pay way more :

Python/`joblib.Parallel()delayed()` constructor is trivial to type, not so for fine-tuning the performance towards a maximum efficiency.

Using a default value of `njobs` ( or any naive manual setting ) may and will most often decrease the actual efficiency of the processing way under the CPU-hardware performance limits.

There are ***non-zero*** add-on costs, that the `joblib`-spawned processes have to pay. In all cases these pay CPU-hardware add-on costs for each data item re-fetched back from RAM again into the (now O/S scheduler re-selected) CPU-core L3/L2/L1-cache (those `~ 3++ [ns]` hundreds nanoseconds) plus it "shares" a weakly prioritised share of the CPU-core code-execution time ( ref. O/S parametrisation and scheduler properties for details on settings for maximum performance / efficiency )
and
***last-but-not-least***
there are immense ( in scale `~ hundreds of [us] if not [ms]` ) add-on costs for the process-instantiation, process-to-process call-signature parameters' transfer ( read SER/DES costs ( often the `pickle.dumps() / pickle.loads()` ) on parameters' data-transformation + Process-2-Process compressed-data communication exchange<sub>*...( time, time, time... )...*</sub>, process-results' data transfer back (if present), i.e. again the SER/DES-pipeline + P2P-communication costs <sub>*...( time, time, time... )...*</sub> plus the process-termination add-on costs.

Doing all this anywhere near the CPU-hardware top performance capabilities ceilings is **always hard**, the more in the relaxed & diverse ecosystem where Python-GIL-lock restricted code-execution + `joblib.Parallel()`-spawned processes + Cython-ised modules (where you need not have the comfort of controlling/tuning the actual number of their spawned sub-processes, do you?) coexist and this already ***"efficiency"*-tuning** wild mix is let being operated inside an ordinary, COTS-grade user-MMI-focused O/S.

---

### If all above was easy to *"swallow"*, the add-on costs of sharing come next :

While the shared-variables protocols exist, I would take whatever measures it takes to avoid paying immense code-execution add-on costs for "using" them.

Who would pay the immense costs to "rent" a Rolls-Royce just for a lazy ride to school at 9:00 AM and to return sometimes in the late afternoon? **Doable, yet an immensely expensive *"strategy"***. There are for sure ways to avoid shared-variables and zero-sharing is a must for any HPC-grade software that aims to top-performance with efficiency in mind.

---

> *"I am working on a project..."*

### Paying the bill only after `XY-[man*months]` of burnt efforts may be too late :

Analyze the processing-strategy and all the actual add-on costs a priori the decision.

**Late surprises are the most expensive ones.**

Even the original, [overhead-naive & atomicity-of-work ignoring Amdahl's Law](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3) shows, that there is a principal limit - a law of diminishing returns - that you can never circumvent. And that was the add-on costs ignoring **optimistic model.**

[image]

The reality works against your will to get improved performance. The more if macroscopic (multi-processing related) add-on costs take (and they very soon do) dominance. Adding shared-variable communication protocols makes the efficiency many orders of magnitude worse (not only `~2` orders of magnitude latency costs added for cache/RAM re-fetches, but process-to-process re-synchronisation costs "block" free-flow of the most efficient CPU-core camped processing, as dependencies on other off-CPU-core processes arise barrier-like blocking states, when shared-variable's state is checked/re-propagated so as to maintain a system-wide consistency ... at the costs of loosing time and efficiency going to turn wreck havoc ... just for the ease of syntax-sugar of Python shared-variable *"comfort"*.

> Yes, the real life is cruel ...
> <sub>*But who has ever told us it isn't?
>
> **Good luck** with managing the Project safe & right!
>
> Learning the Art of Life, going the hard-way forwards, is always enriching us, isn't it?
>
>  :o)*</sub>

---

### May like to read *more* on this,
perhaps with code-examples :

If interested in further readings on [**`joblib`** & revised-Amdahl's Law impacts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A3666197%20%5Bparallelism-amdahl%5D%20is%3Aanswer), feel free to dive in. The Devil is hidden in the details. As always.

Comment: I see, thank you for the detailed response, I'll look further into the resources you provided as I wasn't sure how complicated this would be when I first dove in. In regards to the "why", I modified my submission to give details about what each parallel loop was required for.